# Page Redirect When Div Activate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, css

I have a tile based game, the tiles are made up of 25x30 divs 16x16px each. I have onscreen controls to move the character and when you click a direction the player id updates to the div corresponding with the arrow you clicked. Is it possible to load a new page when the player id is added to a certain div.

For example

```
<div id="player"><img src="assets/img/charcter/ash.png"/></div>
Player ID

<div id="13_5" class="mapsquare teleporttile"></div>
Teleport div
```

If I use the arrow keys to move my player onto the div with the teleportrile class, is it possible to then load a webpage in the same window? I cant think of anyway to do this thanks!

Comment: Do u have any jQuery code for us?, and have you looked at ajax?

Comment: You could probably retrieve the next level configurations using AJAX and render the new level in an element of the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you would like to switch to another page when the player reaches a certain tile, am I ok?

Why instead of changing the id of the div for the player's id don't you check if the tile class is a special one (i.e. teleporttile)?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you? I want to keep the player id the same but check if the player div is inside a teleport tile if = true then load a new page

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. You want to load a new page on the same window or tab where the actual "board" is rigth?
I guess you have a method on your onscreen controls in which you change div id's every time the player "moves", rigth?

Comment: Ok so in that method you can check whether the new tile is of a special type and do something about it. I'll write some pseudo code. Let's say, for example, 'if(destinationTile.hasClass("teleporttile")) { redirect to new page } else { WHAT YOU DO NOW }'. Is it clearer now? :D